# Prevent LUKS Volume from Automatically Mounting

Tags: automount, luks

I have several LUKS volumes on an external drive. When I attach the drive, I would like to prevent two of the LUKS volumes from automatically mounting.

Using `noauto` on the UUIDs in `/etc/fstab` doesn't prevent them from mounting. I'm not sure what else to try.